# How to debug firebase_admin on python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am having trouble debugging firebase_admin.

I know that my auth token is working, as the login bit works, but the second I try to access a document from the firestore, things get "silent".

Doing this:

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
def getUserByUID(uid):
    print(uid)
    db = firestore.client()
    print('before')
    user = db.collection(u'users').document(uid).get().to_dict()
    print(user)
    print('after')
    if not user:
        raise Exception(f"The user requested with the uid: {uid} does not exist in Users collection")
    if not user.get("uid", None):
         user["uid"] = uid
    return user
```

Results in:

```
8XXXXXXXXXXXXX1 
before
```

I can see the document in firestore. It is there and it has a lot of values.

But when doing this:

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
def getUserByUID(uid):
    print(uid)
    db = firestore.client()
    print('before')
    user = db.collection(u'users').document(uid)
    print('after')
    if not user:
         raise Exception(f"The user requested with the uid: {uid} does not exist in Users collection")
    if not user.get("uid", None):
         user["uid"] = uid
    return user
```

I can see this:

```
 8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1
 before
 <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x1CCCCC0>
 after
```

It is just failing silently and I don't see any option to debug this.

Any hint is really welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a broken firebase-admin installation via PIP. Not sure why there is no debugging function, but now it is working again.

Try reinstalling firebase-admin if you are facing the same issue.